Behavior of translation functors in characteristic $p$
Let $G$ be a semisimple and simply connected algebraic group over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$, and let $\mathfrak g$ be the Lie algebra of $G$. Let $U_\chi(\mathfrak g)$ be the quotient of $U(\mathfrak g)$ by the ideal generated by all $x^p-x^{[p]}-\chi(x)^p$ with $x \in \mathfrak g$. Let $\mathcal C_\lambda$ denote the category of finite-dimensional $U_\chi(\mathfrak g)$-modules all of whose composition factors have the same central character as the baby Verma module $Z_\chi(\lambda)$. There is an exact functor $\rm pr_\lambda: \mathcal C \to \mathcal C_\lambda$. The translation functor $T_\lambda^\mu: \mathcal C_\lambda \to \mathcal C_\mu$ is defined by $T_\lambda^\mu(V)={\rm pr}_\mu(E \otimes V)$ where $E$ is the simple $G$-module with highest weight in $W(\mu-\lambda)$. It is known that $T_\lambda^\mu$ and $T_\mu^\lambda$ are adjoint functors, so there is an adjunction morphism $Id \to T_\mu^\lambda T_\lambda^\mu$.
Question: if $M$ is a simple module, is it true that either $ T_\mu^\lambda T_\lambda^\mu(M)$ is zero, or $M \to T_\mu^\lambda T_\lambda^\mu(M)$ is injective and $T_\mu^\lambda T_\lambda^\mu(M)/M$ is a simple module?
